# calling a form from 2 different methods

Tags: c#, forms, button

I am am trying to access a form from a button which sends over data, and a menustrip button that just looks at the form, no data transferred.

to send the data over I have the class name being:

```
    public xSecForm(string dataRecieved)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        xSavedList.Text = dataRecieved;
    }
```

this allows me to send data over on the first button.

Ive seen other help saying to put

```
    xSecForm f2 = new xSecForm()
    f2.Show();
```

in the menu button to just show the window without data passing, but because of the 
(string dataRecieved) at the end of the form it keeps giving me errors.

I was hoping there may be a way to do it without changing how the data is being sent over.

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/267820/How-to-transfer-data-from-one-form-to-another-form)

Comment: _What do the errors say_?

Comment: You could have more than one constructor-- one that passes data and one that does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of methods you can try, each have their benefits and drawbacks.

1) You can have 2 constructors for your second form. One would be default (would not pass in data), and the other would allow you to pass in a string.

```
public xSecForm(string dataReceived)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    xSavedList.Text = dataReceived;
}

public xSecForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

This way you can make a new instance of the second form with or without sending the string in. The drawback is that you can only pass in data when you first create the object.

2) Make a public property in your second form to allow the first form to inject data in itself. In your second form:

```
public string SavedListData
{
    set { xSavedList.Text = value; }
    get { return xSavedList.Text; }
}
```

Then on your main form (assuming you have a default constructor)

```
xSecForm f2 = new xSecForm();
f2.SavedListData = "asdf";
f2.Show();
```

The benefit for this approach is that you can get/set the data whenever, even after you have loaded and have used the second form.

Comment: I like the first solution you put, but for some reason it will not open the second form.

Comment: Nevermind, forgot to give it a click command. just gotta figure out a way for it to not delete my saved information my other button adds on click.